# Hand and Foot Rules on playing all cards without going out

Tags: hand-and-foot

In hand and Foot can a player lay down all cards in their foot, discard the final card and NOT have the required books to go out but continue to draw two cards each turn and discard one until they finally complete their books or someone else goes out?

Answer (score 1):

I've never played this game but have read the at rules [here](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/hand-and-foot/). they say

> To 'Go Out', the player must get a Clean and Dirty, and get completely
> rid of the cards. Players must discard the final card, and not 'simply
> run out of cards'.

So to me this reads if you have 'simply run out of cards' then you have not 'gone out'.   It also suggests that having a Clean and Dirty book is a requirement for going out so even if you have no cards but not the required books you have not 'gone out'

You would continue to play as normal until you had the required Clean and Dirty books or another player 'goes out'

Answer (score 0):

By definition, going out means that you have played all your cards. If someone plays all their cards, That round is over. Everyone will tally their cards if your team has met the requirements for going out. If someone on your team goes out and has not met their requirements, your team loses.

There are minor variations in the rules. In our rules, drawing starts your turn and ends with a discard. If you play all your cards and have no discard, your turn can never end, and your team forfeits the game. If you play all your cards except one and discard that one card, you have legally gone out.

I have written the rules we use here: https://gameofhandandfoot.blogspot.com/.